# Android command line tools not installing correctly?

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

I'd like to start developing a `react-native` app, and to do that I need an emulator. I am on an Ubuntu virtual machine, so I figured just using the command line tools would be fine. After fumbling around for a bit I ran

```
$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager --include_obsolete --update
```

and

```
$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
```

Both returned "done" pretty quickly.

I tried to create an image to load up in the emulator...

```
$ANDROID_HOME/bin/avdmanager create avd --name "testbed" -k "system-
images;android-26;x64"                                                                                                                                                                

Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
```

And no system images are listed. How do I download system images properly?